# Java Filter modified response is getting truncated

Tags: java, spring, filter

I have a spring java application that has a EncryptDecryptFilter.java which is a "OncePerRequestFilter" within which I am trying to modify the response payload based on certain conditions. All is going well for happy path.

During the un-happy path, when my application code in the RestController throws an exception, that exception is captured by a @ControllerAdvice class and the controller advice class returns a ResponseEntity. Let's say this response is "string1" with a length 105 characters. After this, the call is intercepted by the "OncePerRequestFilter" and when I attempt to modify the response in this filter with a new response, lets say the modified response is "string2" with a length 200 characters, the modified response string2 is truncated to 105 characters and delievered to the client. So, while the response it self is being modified, the setContentLength() on the response has no effect.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

See `response.setContentLength(encryptedResponse.length());` in the below filter

```java
@Component
public class EncryptDecryptFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    public static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                                            .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new GsonExclusionStrategy())
                                            .setPrettyPrinting()
                                            .create();

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        String requestMethod = request.getMethod();

        HttpServletRequest requestToUse = new ResettableStreamHttpServletRequest(request);
        BufferResponseWrapper responseToUse = new BufferResponseWrapper(response); // declared as a member of this filter class below

        interceptRequest(requestToUse, request);
        filterChain.doFilter(requestToUse, responseToUse);
        interceptResponse(response, responseToUse);
    }

    private void interceptRequest(HttpServletRequest requestToUse, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        byte[] payload = IOUtils.toByteArray(requestToUse.getReader(), requestToUse.getCharacterEncoding());
        String urlEncodedEncryptedBody = new String(payload, requestToUse.getCharacterEncoding());
        System.out.println(urlEncodedEncryptedBody);
        AesDecryptionRequest decryptionRequest = gson.fromJson(urlEncodedEncryptedBody, AesDecryptionRequest.class);
        decryptionRequest.initialize();
        String plainTextBody = AesUtil.decrypt(decryptionRequest);
        requestToUse.setAttribute("requestBody", plainTextBody);
    }

    private void interceptResponse(HttpServletResponse response, BufferResponseWrapper responseToUse) throws IOException {
        String responseStr = new String(responseToUse.getWrapperBytes());
        System.out.println(responseStr); // full response string with length 105 from @ControllerAdvice
        AesEncryptionResponse encryptionResponse = AesUtil.encrypt(responseStr);
        String encryptedResponse = gson.toJson(encryptionResponse); // encrypted form of @ControllerAdvice response length 200n chars
        response.setContentLength(encryptedResponse.length()); // this does not seem to have any effect, the response is still truncated to 105 chars
        response.getOutputStream().write(encryptedResponse.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }


    private final class BufferResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper
    {
        MyServletOutputStream stream = new MyServletOutputStream();

        public BufferResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
        {
            super(httpServletResponse);
        }

        public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException
        {
            return stream;
        }

        public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException
        {
            return new PrintWriter(stream);
        }

        public byte[] getWrapperBytes()
        {
            return stream.getBytes();
        }
    }

    private final class MyServletOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream
    {
        private ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        public void write(int b) throws IOException
        {
            out.write(b);
        }

        public byte[] getBytes()
        {
            return out.toByteArray();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReady() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void setWriteListener(WriteListener writeListener) {

        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class ResettableStreamHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    // this class allows the input stream to be read more than once

    private static final String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";
    private byte[] rawData;
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private ResettableServletInputStream servletStream;


    public ResettableStreamHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        this.request = request;
        this.servletStream = new ResettableServletInputStream();
    }

    public void resetInputStream() {
        servletStream.stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawData);
    }

    public void resetInputStream(byte[] newRawData) {
        servletStream.stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(newRawData);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        if (rawData == null) {
            rawData = IOUtils.toByteArray(this.request.getReader(), UTF_8);
            servletStream.stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawData);
        }
        return servletStream;
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        if (rawData == null) {
            rawData = IOUtils.toByteArray(this.request.getReader(), UTF_8);
            servletStream.stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawData);
        }
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(servletStream, UTF_8));
    }

    private class ResettableServletInputStream extends ServletInputStream {
        private ByteArrayInputStream stream;

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return stream.read();
        }

        @Override
        // Returns true when all the data from the stream has been read else it returns false.
        public boolean isFinished() {
            return stream.available() == 0;
        }

        @Override
        // Returns true if data can be read without blocking else returns false.
        public boolean isReady() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void setReadListener(ReadListener listener) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not implemented");
        }
    }
}
```

Controller Advice class

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {Exception.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception exception, WebRequest request) {
        return handleExceptionInternal(exception, exception.getMessage(), getStandardHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request);
    }
}
```

Comment: After fighting the design, I abandoned approaching my  decryption / encryption of payload  from a filter to individual rest controller methods as I could not sacrifice the controller advice functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.reset()` method on response object before you rewrite it.

```
private void interceptResponse(HttpServletResponse response, BufferResponseWrapper responseToUse) throws IOException {
        String responseStr = new String(responseToUse.getWrapperBytes());
        System.out.println(responseStr); // full response string with length 105 from @ControllerAdvice
        AesEncryptionResponse encryptionResponse = AesUtil.encrypt(responseStr);
        String encryptedResponse = gson.toJson(encryptionResponse); // encrypted form of @ControllerAdvice response length 200n chars
       
        response.reset(); <-------------
        response.setContentLength(encryptedResponse.length()); // this does not seem to have any effect, the response is still truncated to 105 chars
        response.getOutputStream().write(encryptedResponse.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
```

According to the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#resetBuffer())

> void reset() Clears any data that exists in the buffer as well as the
> status code and **headers**. If the response has been committed, this
> method throws an IllegalStateException.
>
> Throws: IllegalStateException
>
> - if the response has already been committed

Comment: Jus tried this, does not work. Looks like the response is already committed and I am receiving "IllegalStateException"